# Access Querys states wrong number of arguments

Tags: ms-access

I can't seem to get this to work - states that the expression has the wrong number of arguments. Any ideas???

Age Bucket: IIf(Date()-[RCV_RCV_DATE]<31,"0-30",IIf(Date()-[RCV_RCV_DATE]) Between 31 And 60.999999,”31-60”,IIf(Date()-[RCV_RCV_DATE]) Between 61 And 90.999999,”90”,”120”)))

I am trying to age my items into groups.

Thanks

Comment: Is RCV_RCV_DATE a field in the table you are querying? Are you sure?

Comment: Wrong parenthesis closing! Check the nested `iif`s.

Answer (score 1):

Two extra closing parens,  see "^" below

```
IIf(Date()-[RCV_RCV_DATE]<31,

    "0-30",

    IIf(Date()-[RCV_RCV_DATE]) Between 31 And 60.999999,
                             ^
        "31-60",

        IIf(Date()-[RCV_RCV_DATE]) Between 61 And 90.999999,
                                 ^
            "90",

            "120"
           )
        )
     )
```